# GitHub actions push to remote repo

Tags: github, github-actions

How can I push some files that were generated by the runner (`user1/repo1`) to the *main* branch from another remote repo (`user2/repo1`) via GitHub actions?

Please note that:

- I set-up a secret key (named `ACCESS_TOKEN`) in `user1/repo1`, such that it corresponds to the Personal Access Token from the destination repo (`user2/repo1`)
- the GitHub actions needs to be repeated every ~30 minutes
- there already exists a `file.rds` in the destination repo. The push thus needs to *override* that file every time
- the runner needs to be `macOS-latest`

This is what I have tried so far:

```yaml
name: gitaction

on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  "*/30 * * * *"
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs: 
  genFileAndPush:
    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master
      with:
         r-version: '4.1.2'

    - name: Run R scripts and generate file
      run: |
        saveRDS(1:3, file = "file.rds")
      shell: Rscript {0}

    - name: Push to remote repository
      run: |
        git config --local user.name actions-user
        git config --local user.email "actions@github.com"
        git add file.rds
        git commit -m "commit"
        git remote set-url origin https://env.REPO_KEY@github.com/user2/repo1.git
        git push -u origin main
      env:
        REPO_KEY: ${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN}}
        username: github-actions
```

It returns the following error:

```yaml
remote: Permission to user2/repo1.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user2/repo1.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

What am I missing?

---

**Edit**
As suggested, I tried using `GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push@v1.1`:

```yaml
name: gitaction

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs: 
  genFileAndPush:
    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master
      with:
         r-version: '4.1.2'

    - name: Run R scripts and generate file
      run: |
        saveRDS(1:3, file = "file.rds")
      shell: Rscript {0}

    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
    - uses: GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push@v1.1
      with:
        target_branch: main
        files: file.rds
        remote_repository: https://github.com/user2/repo1
        access_token: ${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN}}
        force: true
```

Although there were no error, the file was not pushed (because it was not detected?):

```yaml
Run GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push@v1.1
Run CURRENT_BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF}
WARNING: No changes were detected. git commit push action aborted.
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe not sure what you mean by 'manually'? I've made some edit to my post, please if this clarifies your question

Comment: You've completely changed the key, so it doesn't matter. But `https://env.REPO_KEY@github.com/user2/repo1.git` looks suspicious - don't you mean `https://$REPO_KEY@github.com/user2/repo1.git`? The default shell for macOS runners is bash.

Comment: I tried with `$REPO_KEY` and I get the same error. (I changed the name of the key because github wouldn't allow me to setup a secret starting with `GITHUB_`)

Comment: As others pointed out, correct syntax would be either `https://$REPO_KEY@github.com/user2/repo1.git` or `https://${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN}}@github.com/user2/repo1.git`.  But if it's complaining about permissions, I'd double check the token. Try checking out other repo...Also, you're missing `commit` command.

Comment: There are also some actions on the Github Marketplace that can help you with pushing files to other repositories. [Here is an example of one](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push). You can find more actions like this one [here](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=commit+push).

Comment: @frennky Tried both syntaxes, double checked the token, added the `git commit -m "commit"` line, and it is still not working...

Comment: @GuiFalourd Thank you for the reference, I am currently using `andstor/copycat-action@v3` , but I seek to improve the efficiency of the process, by not having to call another action on the market place.

Comment: @GuiFalourd I tried your suggestion but I am struggling. I updated my post, please have a look.

Comment: You don't need to use the `actions/checkout` twice in that case, the first step should be enough. Did you check the `file.rds` was updated related to the target repo `main` branch? The action stated that the file.rds generated in the workflow is the same that the one already present on that branch. I see 2 possible scenarios here, or the file hasn't been updated, or it hasn't been generated.

Comment: @GuiFalourd The target repository is empty... Perhaps I need to push the file to the current repository (`user1/repo1`) before I can push it to the remote one? I am stuck..

Comment: Can you share the first repository (the one with the workflow) to check the `file.rds` file and make some tests using a fork?

Comment: It seems the problem was with the action. I updated it to `v1.2` and if you use `uses: GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push@v1.2` in your workflow, it should now work as expected. I tested it on my fork: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/test/runs/4734736194?check_suite_focus=true and the updated repo can be found here: https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/repo1/tree/main

Comment: I just updated the `v1.2` version to support it (I didn't remember this scenario at first), if you can to try it again removing the last step comment here: https://github.com/githubktwoo/genpage/blob/main/.github/workflows/main.yml :)

Comment: Ok, I'm checking

Comment: I just generated a `v1.3` if you use `uses: GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push@v1.3` in your workflow, it should now work as expected (sorry for all the updates, there are many things to check each time and I'm adding functional tests to validate new scenarios).

Comment: @GuiFalourd Seems to work perfectly, merci bcp! Feel free to post the answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some actions on the Github Marketplace that can help you with pushing files to other repositories.

- [Here is an example of one supported on all OS runners.](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push)

**The workflow would look like this:**

```yaml
name: gitaction

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs: 
  genFileAndPush:
    runs-on: macOS-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master
      with:
         r-version: '4.1.2'

    - name: Run R scripts and generate file
      run: |
        saveRDS(1:3, file = "file.rds")
      shell: Rscript {0}

    - uses: GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push@v1.3
      with:
        target_branch: main
        files: file.rds
        remote_repository: https://github.com/user2/repo1
        access_token: ${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN}}
        force: true
```

- [You can find more actions like this one on the marketplace.](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=commit%20push)

Otherwise, you can also perform the whole operation manually using command lines to clone the remote repository, copy the files from the local repo wherever you want on the remote repo, then push the new files to the remote repository.